# Javascript annotations / decorators on normal functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, next.js, annotations

I am developing a Next.js application, and I have an API defined in the following way:

```
export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    fn1Get(req, res);
  } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
    fn1Post(req, res);
  } else {
    res.status(501).json({ operation: `${req.method}: not implemented` });
  }
}
```

```
async function fn1Get(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
  const authenticated = await checkAuth(req, res);
  if (authenticated) {
      // Get Stuff
      res.status(200).json({status: 'all right!'});
  }
}
```

```
async function fn1Post(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
  const authenticated = await checkAuth(req, res);
  if (authenticated) {
      // Post Stuff
      res.status(201).json({status: 'all right!'});
  }
}
```

```
const checkAuth = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const tokenValid = await extnernalApiCall(getToken(req));
  if (!tokenValid) {
    res.status(403).json({ error: 'Authentication Failed' });
  }
  return tokenValid
};
```

I am trying to find an easier setup to define authenticated methods, instead of adding inside of them the line `const authenticated = await checkAuth(req, res);`

In other languages like Java or Python I could use decorators / annotations / AOP, something like:

```
@checkAuth
async function fn1Get(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
):
```

Can I do something close to it in javascript? Maybe via wrapping functions, and/or using bind/call/apply??

Pseudo-code example:

```
const checkAuth = async (fn) => {
  const req = arguments[1];
  const res = arguments[2];
  const tokenValid = await extnernalApiCall(getToken(req));
  if (!tokenValid) {
    res.status(403).json({ error: 'Authentication Failed' });
  }
  return fn(arguments);
}
async function fn1Get = checkAuth(_fn1Get(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
  const authenticated = await checkAuth(req, res);
  if (authenticated) {
      // Get Stuff
      res.status(200).json({status: 'all right!'});
  }
})
```

As you can see, all the functions that I want to authenticate will receive the same two parameters `req` and `res` (request and response), and my authentication function also need both parameters to get the token to authenticate from the `req` and write a 403 in `res` if it is not authenticated

The technologies I'm using are Next.js with React 17, TypeScript, ECMA6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with a wrapper function (that's basically what decorators are anyway). That wrapper function has to return a function. Something like the following (you'll have to adjust the types accordingly):

```
const checkAuth = (fn) => {
  return async (req: NextApiRequest,res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
    const tokenValid = await extnernalApiCall(getToken(req));
    if (!tokenValid) {
      res.status(403).json({ error: 'Authentication Failed' });
    } else {
      fn(req, res);
    }
  }
}

const fn1Get = checkAuth((
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> => {
  // Get Stuff
  res.status(200).json({status: 'all right!'});
})
```

Having said that, I'm not familiar with next.js. There might be a way to register middelware handlers that would fire on every request without you having to wrap every handler explicitly.

Comment: Damn! I was actually really close!! Thank you very much!! You are missing an arrow though in fn1Get: `: Promise<void> => {` Please, edit it for other people who reads the answer!! =)

Answer (score 0):

I use next js along with next-auth for authentication.
I made a function that checks if the request has a session. If no session, the user gets redirected to the sign in page. If the user has a session, it passes the props to **getServerSideProps** function.

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

/* gssp =  */
export const requireAuth = (gssp) => {
  return async (ctx) => {
      const { req } = ctx;
      const session = await getSession({ req })
      if (!session) {
          return {
              redirect: { permanent: false, destination: '/api/auth/signin' }
          };
      };
      const ctxWithSession = { ...ctx, session };
      return await gssp(ctxWithSession);
  };
};
```

Then, i call this function in my next js page as a higher function of **getServerSideProps** :

```
export const getServerSideProps = requireAuth(async _ctx => {
    const { session } = _ctx;
    return {
        props: {
          session: session,  
        },
    };
});
```